# Gson 'fromJson' issue

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to bind JSON to Java POJO class using `com.google.gson.Gson`
like this :

```
MyClass data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

When I am using below mentioned it's working fine

```
{
    "data": "{\"key1\":{\"key11\":\"192.192.1.192\",\"key12\":\"WEB\"}}"
}
```

However, when below-mentioned data is used, I am getting `MalformedJsonException`

```
{
    "data": "{"key1":{"key11":"192.168.1.158","key12":"WEB"}}"
}
```

Log :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: 
Unterminated object at line 1 column 354 path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `"` within a `String` to quote your JSON keys and values. You either have to escape them (like you did in your first example) or you have use single quotes `'`.

You are effectively trying to do String concatenation without using `+`.

This looks for the compiler like a list of Strings with variables in between:

```
"{"key1":{"key11":"192.168.1.158","key12":"WEB"}}"
```

The compiler would expect something like this:

```
"{" + key1 + ":{" + key11 + ":" + 192.168.1.158 + "," + key12 + ":" + WEB + "}}";
```

If you look at the String this way you immediately see the problem. That's why you should either escape the quotes or use single quotes:

```
"{\"key1\":{\"key11\":\"192.168.1.158\",\"key12\":\"WEB\"}}"
"{'key1':{'key11':'192.168.1.158','key12':'WEB'}}"
```